# Expand div height by pixels

Tags: html, css

I have a div I want to expand using CSS by some amount relative to its *initial* height. I neither know nor care about what that initial height is - I simply want to make it "x px taller".

So, for example, if the initial height of the div is 100px, on mouseover (or class apply or whatever), I want it to become 105px tall. If the initial height is 50px, I want it to become 55px tall. Etc.

A sample use case would be to have an item "pop out" when mousing over it. Alternative, it could indicate which of a number of objects is currently selected (i.e. has a "selected" class) by making objects with a "selected" class slightly larger.

Comment: add a padding bottom equal to Xpx ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok, now I just feel stupid for not thinking of that :-P Yeah, that should work nicely. Feel free to add that as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the css transform for scale and even add it to the hover selector, like this: https://codepen.io/rachelcope/pen/gbxxXe

```
&:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

This will give it a nice animation / effect that keeps all content within the object in the correct place.

Comment: Nice option, but has the unfortunate side effect of the size change not being reflected in surrounding/enclosing objects. I'll have to mull over it a bit, see if there is some way to work around that. Still, has the desired effect otherwise!